# How to design a storage system for this?

Tags: java, database

I am really stuck at designing for a database for this.

This is my own CS project. That means this entire code is my idea. Anyways, I would like to know the most efficient way to store all of the information shown in the picture.

I thought about using ArrayList, but I questioned myself repetitively whether arraylist would work. I could probably use database but I haven't learned it yet.

The picture should be pretty self-explainatory. All of these information only belong to 1 student. So, how can I designed the best data storage system to store at least 20 students' information?

Since I can't post image, please click this link: http://j.stack.imr.com/0Q.png

Thanks for help.

Comment: database i think would be best. Install XAMPP so you can run local MySQL database. Create appropriate tables. Then you can do SaveActionPerformed and on that method have all the values inserted into field be passed to your local DB.

Comment: What do you want to use this system for ?

Comment: Database would be wise... probably can get away with xml and excel if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a case for one database table with one row per student, and another database table with a row per assignment.  I would either have the database create an index for each student record as I stored it (the current fashion in relational databases), or I could use the student ID number assuming it is unique and permanent (I consider it a weaker choice).  Every student record and every assignment record has this index in it, so that every assignment is associated with one and only one student, but you can have many assignments associated with one student.

There are a number of free databases available; I have used and liked Derby; if you are only accessing it from this program, you can use it as an "embedded" database, saving yourself some headache running a database server for your program to connect with.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it will be via Database i believe.
 Since you have mentioned you dont know much about DB let me point you in the right direction
First of all install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) (this will allow you to create MySQL database on your local machine)

You have to install JDBC Drivers into your IDE (netbeans or eclipse whatever you are using)

In your project create a class more or less like this one

```
public class SQLConnect 
{
    public static Connection ConnectDb() 
    {
      try
      {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/w1283057", "root", "");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SQLConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
          return conn;
      }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
      {
         System.out.println("not connected");
         e.printStackTrace();//print extra info if error is thrown
         return null; 
      }

  }


}
```

then you can create SaveActionPerformed on your other class (where you have the form table whatever)
It may look something like this (Please not this is where you make your connection with the SQLConnect Class and where you insert data into Database

```
public class Something extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
      Connection conn = null; //A connection (session) with a specific database
      ResultSet rs = null; //A table of data representing a database result set, which is usually generated by executing a statement that queries the database.
      PreparedStatement pst = null; //An object that represents a precompiled SQL statement.A SQL statement is precompiled and stored in that object

     private void SaveActionPerformed(jawa.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
     {  
        try{
        conn = SQLConnect.ConnectDb();
        //inserting all values to database            
        String sql = "INSERT INTO bla"
                   + "(foo, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, etc"
                   + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";  
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    //Than you take all values from the fields and put them into db
    // i.e. You have field name Mark. In order to put this into db you need 

     pst.setString(1, Mark);  <- this means that preparestatement will put whatever is in the mark into first column.
     pst.executeUpdate(); <- order to execute

      }
```

Hopefully this will put you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

for me the best way to do it is by using Postgresql. You just need a table student (for example) where will be stored all the student data.
After that you can create a class or more than one (that depends on you) who will describe the table and will perform some actions like search student or whatever.
The main advantage of Postgresql is that doesn't require a server!
Here is a [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqljavatutorial/)